# jQuery: Cannot check if radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following form:

```
    <div class="form-radios">

    <!-- OPTION #1 -->

    <div class="form-item form-type-radio">             
        <input type="radio" name="auswahl_radio" id="option1" class="form-radio">  <label class="option" for="option1">Option 1</label>

        <div class="radio-supplement">
            <p>Please accept:</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" value="beer"><a href="#">Checkbox 1</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" value="wine"><a href="#">Checkbox 2</a>
        </div>      

    </div>


    <!-- OPTION #2 -->

    <div class="form-item form-type-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="auswahl_radio" id="option2" class="form-radio">  <label class="option" for="option2">Option 2 </label>
    </div>


    <!-- OPTION #3 -->

    <div class="form-item form-type-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="auswahl_radio" id="option3" class="form-radio">  <label class="option" for="option3">Option 3</label>
    </div>

    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is that **when the user clicks the submit-button and checked OPTION #1, then my script shall check if both checkboxes in the containing div.radio-supplement are checked.** If not at least one of them is checked, the form must not be sent.

Here is the relevant jQuery script I came up with but doesn't work:

```
var checkbox_1 = $('#checkbox_1').prop('checked');  
var checkbox_2 = $('#checkbox_2').prop('checked');

     if ($("#option1").is(':checked')) {

         if ( (checkbox_1 == true) && (checkbox_2 == true) ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $('.messages_error').html('At option1 please check both checkboxes');
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                return false;
         };

     };
```

Does anyone of you see the error?

Comment: Do you trigger the script with an `onclick` event (or jquery `click`)?

Comment: @Thundar with jquery $('#button').on('click', function() { ... });

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var radios = jQuery("input[name='auswahl_radio']");
var radio_is_checked = radios.filter(":checked") ;
```

THEN check for this radio_is_checked variable.